# How to compile wth gcc , intel static libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, intel, icc

I have a program which I compile with gcc.
I got a static library (.a file) which was compiled with Intel compiler (icc).

How can I use and linked with that library ? (I dont have icc and the other side must use icc in order to use Intel instructions sets).

I'm trying to compile (link with that library) but I'm getting error on Intel instructions...

- My target has Intel I7.
- The first error I'm getting is: "undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'"

Thanks

Comment: *What* errors do you get? *How* do you try to link with the library? And your target platform *is* some "Intel" based system?

Comment: The `__intel_fast_memcpy` function looks like an internal function used by the ICC compiler, it's probably part of the ICC runtime support library. If you don't have that then there's really nothing you can do. But you *do* know that ICC is [free for some non-commercial uses](https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software)?

Comment: For that particular function, [it's obviously a memcpy-like function], you can create a .c that defines it as an "alias" to a real memcpy function: `extern ... _intel_fast_memcpy ... __attribute__((alias(real_memcpy)))`.  For others, a wrapper function that defines the given __intel* function and calls [possibly morphing args] a real function.  If you encounter one that you don't understand, there may docs that explain it.  Should be a tractable number of functions you have to stub out

Comment: Googling, if found [this article](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/310493), that points into using Intel's linker as a solution.

Comment: Hi,
If I request to get the libraries as shared libraries (compiled with intel) It will work ?

Answer (score 3):

Please look into the recommendation provided at Intel C++ Compiler forum thread: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/310493. Hope this helps.